# Starting App in debug mode with Braintree's hosted-fields

Tags: vue.js

In my Vue app, I have a web payment module implementing Braintree. It works fine, however, when I try to start the project in dev mode, I get the following message:

```
Error: The following dependencies are imported but could not be resolved:

  braintree-web/modules/hosted-fields (imported by /Users/paoloagva/Documents/dev/order/src/main/frontend/checkout/app/components/checkout/payment/creditcard/CreditCardInput.vue?id=0)

Are they installed?
    at file:///Users/paoloagva/Documents/dev/order/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-e8f070e8.js:44188:23
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async file:///Users/paguilar/Documents/dev/order/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-e8f070e8.js:43597:38
```

I am importing it as follows:

```
import { HostedFieldsHostedFieldsFieldName } from 'braintree-web/modules/hosted-fields';
```

In Production it works fine, I am just not able to debug it. Anyone has an idea of what the issue could be?